# Make .replaceWith and .css jquery work together

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have the following code:

```
    $(function () {
        var search = $("#search");
        search.click(function () {
            search.replaceWith($("<img id='search' src='Icons/magnifier.png' >")).css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000", "padding-left": "130px", "transition": "all 500ms" });
        });

        $('html').click(function() {
            search.replaceWith($("<img id='search' src='Icons/magnifier2.png' >")).css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000", "padding-left": "3px", "transition": "all 500ms" });
        });
    })
```

The idea is that when a user clicks on the icon, it changes to a darker color, and the border slides out (it should contain an input box, just havent made it yet) 
As for now, I can get the .css and .replaceWith work individually, but only the icon changes when I chain them together. 
When the user clicks on the body of the html, it should slide back in and change the icon back to the original one. obviously this doesnt happen aswell.

HTML:

```
        <div class="topnav">
            <img id="search" src="Icons/magnifier2.png" />
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.topnav img {
    display:inline;
    border: 2px ridge #7ab5dc;
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to transition the change of images? Because that can't be done with CSS. Maybe if you made a runnable demo it would be easier to see what you’re after.

Comment: no, however that would be great. The transition is only for the border on the padding.

Comment: The proper method would be to add/remove a class onclick instead of using replaceWith, then let the pre-defined CSS classes handle all the transitions.

Comment: Do I get it right if the issue is that the padding doesn’t change?

Comment: yes, thats correct. Only the image does, but if i strip the .replaceWith out and only put in the css, the padding changes. 

With both chained, only the image changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Since the `img` with `id ="search"` is a part of the `html` tag, it will screw up trigger `$('html').click` event everytime. So the approach was to use `target.id` of the `event` to see if the click was actually triggered inside the image. Also, since you are just changing the `src` and `css` of the `img`, you don't need to replace the element.

```
var search = $("#search");
        search.click(function () {
            $(this).attr("src","Icons/magnifier.png");
            $(this).css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000", "padding-left": "130px", "transition": "all 500ms" });
        });



        $('html').click(function(e) {  
            if(e.target.id != 'search')
            {
            $("#search").attr("src","Icons/magnifier2.png");
            $("#search").css({ "border": "2px", "border-style": "ridge", "border-color": "#000000", "padding-left": "3px", "transition": "all 500ms" });
            }
        });
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/v01b216u/5/

Comment: thats great! Can you explain to me, why the replaceWith doesnt work? and why i can do .attr without declaring an id?

Comment: .replaceWith basically replaces the html of the targeted element. In your case, since your selector is an image byitself, it doesn't have an underlying html to change. Check out the explaination here : http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Comment: Also, you need to make sure that the element being replaced with needs to be formatted correctly. In your case, your replaceWith was missing </img>, thats why it didn't work. Here's a working example if you wish to use replacewith : http://jsfiddle.net/v01b216u/7/

Comment: thank you very much. Its nice to see a working example on both, smart idea with the conditional expression, so that users cant toggle search to bring it back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that there’s an event listener active on the `html` element which the `#search` element is a part of. This means when you click the `#search` element both events are triggered and the `html`-event is triggered last making it always change to `magnifier2.png` and `padding: 3px`